# Configuring develop and production enviroment in webroot path on CAKEPHP 3.X

Tags: php, css, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, filepath

I want to have subfolders to develop with sources files like Sass, uminified js and jades ones and another ones with the production files compiled using gulp.

My structure is

- /webroot

  - master/ develop folder (sass, jade ecc)
  - app/ //poduction folder (minified css ecc)

I think that i can set a variable in app.php (?) to set if i'm in develop o production and call it in src/Template/Layout/default.cpt file to define from which path use

`if( {isDevelop} ){
 <?= $this->Html->css('master/css/cake.css') ?>
}else{
 <?= $this->Html->css('app/css/main-style.min.css') ?>`

How can i do? and what is the best way?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to Do it, improving Gransfall answer, is check the debug level.

Wich `debug true`  is for Development Mode, and `debug false` is for Production Mode.

You can change this value at: `config/app.php`.

You can Do it, for example, in your `appController`:

```
use Cake\Core\Configure;

public function beforeFilter(Event $event) {
    $this->set('isDevelop',0);

    if(Configure::read('debug')) {
        $this->set('isDevelop',1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You ca do for example in your appController

```
public function beforeFilter(Event $event)
{

    if($this->request->env('SERVER_ADDR') == '127.0.0.1')
    {
        $this->set('isDevelop',1);
    }
    else
    {
        $this->set('isDevelop',0);
    }
}
```

else you can do it in bootstrap file in config folder with Configure Variable...

Your choice

Comment: You should never access superglobals directly with CakePHP, this will haunt you at some point, especially when running tests. Use `env()` or the request object instead! That being said, such a check isn't an overly good idea, relying on the users IP is kinda wonky (what would that value for example look like on the CLI?). Environment details are best retrieved from environment variables, or environment specific configuration (files).

Comment: @ndm I did not know for the env object in cake thanks for your knowledge ;)